# mule multi language data transfer support via http

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-component

I wanna help in achieving below mule use-case.Mule flow contains http-inbound-endpoint and object-string transformer(optional) and logger which prints the payload.

Requirement is that i am invoking flow with rest client with a json string 


{
"name":"ساختبار",
"age":"25"
}


in the json string name can  of different language for example Arabic language string.

I tried with same implementation with sample json string with name defined in Arabic input string from rest client.But while checking the logger output prints


{
"name":"???????",
"age":"25"
}


instead of actual input.

How i can get the actual Arabic or any language input string printed in logger.

Comment: Is this a character set issue? Are you using, for example, UTF-8 for message conversion and logging?

Comment: Just to make sure: this issue is only with the `logger`? Otherwise, the internal representation is correct? What do you do with the data besides logging?

Comment: Hi David, the issue not only with logger ,just in java component also when i am printing the result the same output is coming.I need to transform the data to XML.

Comment: Hi vikingsteve,I have set the charset to UTF-8 when i am invoking from rest client, the same issue coming .

Comment: If by any chance you are only testing in Studio, I would also try this: https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

Answer (score 1):

As per [forum](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/mule-multi-language-data-transfer-support-via-http), set the correct Eclipse console encoding following [these](https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) instructions and set the appropiate encoding on your endpoints.